# Live camera template matching using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I'm having some trouble identifying an image (Template) using the code provided on the [OpenCV website](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html/). I've been using it with some images captured using the Camera application on my PC (Win10 64bit) and it works really good, but when I try to get the image to compare from the camera, it just shows me a black window with the Track bars:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

/// Global Variables
Mat img;
Mat templ;
Mat result;
char* image_window = "Source Image";
char* result_window = "Result window";

int match_method;
int i=0;
int max_Trackbar = 5;

/// Function Headers
void MatchingMethod( int, void* );

/** @function main enter code heren */
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
if(!cap.isOpened()) // check if we succeeded
    return -1;
for(;;)
{
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame;
    /// Load image and template
    img=frame.clone();
    templ = imread( "Template.jpg", 1 );

    /// Create windows
    namedWindow( image_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    namedWindow( result_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

    /// Create Trackbar
    char* trackbar_label = "Method: \n 0: SQDIFF \n 1: SQDIFF NORMED \n 2: TM CCORR \n 3: TM CCORR NORMED \n 4: TM COEFF \n 5: TM COEFF NORMED";
    createTrackbar( trackbar_label, image_window, &match_method, max_Trackbar, MatchingMethod );

    MatchingMethod( 0, 0 );

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
}

/**
 * @function MatchingMethod
 * @brief Trackbar callback
 */
void MatchingMethod( int, void* )
{
/// Source image to display
Mat img_display;
img.copyTo( img_display );

/// Create the result matrix
int result_cols =  img.cols - templ.cols + 1;
int result_rows = img.rows - templ.rows + 1;

result.create( result_rows, result_cols, CV_32FC1 );

/// Do the Matching and Normalize
matchTemplate( img, templ, result, match_method );
normalize( result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

/// Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc
double minVal;
double maxVal;
Point minLoc;
Point maxLoc;
Point matchLoc;

minMaxLoc( result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat() );

/// For SQDIFF and SQDIFF_NORMED, the best matches are lower values. For all the other methods, the higher the better
if( match_method  == CV_TM_SQDIFF || match_method == CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED )
{
    matchLoc = minLoc;
}
else
{
    matchLoc = maxLoc;
}

/// Show me what you got
rectangle( img_display, matchLoc, Point( matchLoc.x + templ.cols, matchLoc.y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0 );
rectangle( result, matchLoc, Point( matchLoc.x + templ.cols, matchLoc.y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0 );

imshow( image_window, img_display );
imshow( result_window, result );

return;
}
```

The way I think it should work is taking the frame captured on
    `cap>>frame;`
and copying it on the variable img
    `img=frame.clone();`.
Then, it sends it to do the processing each time on the `MatchingMethod` until any key is pressed.

Me and my project mates would really appreciate anything that makes us solve this problem.

PS: 
If there's any doubt about the IDE I'm using, I'm working with Codeblocks. 
Also, I'll attach some links with the results I'm getting: [Link to Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW26L.jpg)

Comment: Just a couple of remarks, 1) `templ = imread( "Template.jpg", 1 );` should be outside the loop, there is no need to load them on every frame. 2) Try displaying the `frame` directly, to see if you are grabbing correctly from the camera... Also change the `waitKey(0)` to `waitKey(30)` this way it will continue in the loop.... and remove the `return 0;` of the loop, it could be that the first frame is black.....(maybe the camera takes a frame to initialize or something) Also, since it is continuos frames, try not to use matching method as the method, just change the matching method with it

Comment: Thank you very much!!
I think that the `Return(0)` was the line responsible for the black frame.
I'll see what other methods are that I can use to track better what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the user [api55](https://stackoverflow.com/users/888688/api55) I was able to do the live matching, but after consulting I found out that this isn't the best method to track a robot, but at least is a small step towards the final solution. I'll be posting updates on the code so it will be helpful to anyone who needs it.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

/// Global Variables
Mat img;
Mat templ;
Mat result;
char* image_window = "Source Image";
char* result_window = "Result window";

int match_method;
int i=0;
int max_Trackbar = 5;

/// Function Headers
void MatchingMethod( int, void* );
void delay();

/** @function main */
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
{
    return -1;
}
templ = imread( "template3.jpg", 1 );
for(;;)
{
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
    if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    while(frame.empty())
    {
        std::cout<<"Frame Vacio"<<std::endl;
    }
    // do any processing
    /// Load image and template
    img=frame.clone();
    //frame.clone();

    /// Create windows
    namedWindow( image_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    namedWindow( result_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

    /// Create Trackbar
    //char* trackbar_label = "Method: \n 0: SQDIFF \n 1: SQDIFF NORMED \n 2: TM CCORR \n 3: TM CCORR NORMED \n 4: TM COEFF \n 5: TM COEFF NORMED";
    //createTrackbar( trackbar_label, image_window, &match_method, max_Trackbar, MatchingMethod );


    MatchingMethod( 0, 0 );

    waitKey(30);

}
return 0;
}

/**
 * @function MatchingMethod
 * @brief Trackbar callback
 */
void MatchingMethod( int, void* )
{
/// Source image to display
Mat img_display;
img.copyTo( img_display );

/// Create the result matrix
int result_cols =  img.cols - templ.cols + 1;
int result_rows = img.rows - templ.rows + 1;

result.create( result_rows, result_cols, CV_32FC1 );

/// Do the Matching and Normalize
matchTemplate( img, templ, result, match_method );
normalize( result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

/// Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc
double minVal;
double maxVal;
Point minLoc;
Point maxLoc;
Point matchLoc;

minMaxLoc( result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat() );

/// For SQDIFF and SQDIFF_NORMED, the best matches are lower values. For all the other methods, the higher the better
if( match_method  == CV_TM_SQDIFF || match_method == CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED )
{
    matchLoc = minLoc;
}
else
{
    matchLoc = maxLoc;
}

/// Show me what you got
rectangle( img_display, matchLoc, Point( matchLoc.x + templ.cols, matchLoc.y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0 );
rectangle( result, matchLoc, Point( matchLoc.x + templ.cols, matchLoc.y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0 );

imshow( image_window, img_display );
imshow( result_window, result );

return;
}
```

Comment: For tracking a robot, you can try different things... such as the trackers in the contrib module of opencv, or camshift, or some opticalflow tracker.